# wordpress adding php files and linking to them

Tags: wordpress

i'm wondering if it's possible to add a php file in your themes folder (wp-content/themes/classic) where the css file is, then link afterwards? Because i'm currently trying to add a register.php into my blog but i still need the header and everything else.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "then link afterwards?" What files are you trying to link and how?

Comment: say, such as a file with php codes, basically just another file.php in the themes then in say header.php i have <a href="file.php">file</a>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. For example, if you want something like www.yourdomain.com/test follow this steps:

1. In your theme folder create a php file called page-test.php.
2. From your dashboard publish a page with the title Test(with no content at all).
3. Now, when you'll go to www.yourdomain.com/test you will se your page. And in page-test.php you can use all Wordpress functions such as get_header(), get_sidebar() etc.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. What you want is to define a new "page" template, and then to create a new page in your wordpress using that template. Here's the WP documentation on that topic: http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Page_Templates

Alternatively, you don't have to place it in your theme folder; you can put it in the root wordpress folder and have it function outside of wordpress. Then you can change your theme to have a static link to that page, or link to it in some other manner. It would be more difficult to use the header/footer/sidebar template features, though.